# Making a form with variable no of checkboxes in Django

Tags: django

Im making a site where people can take tests in Django.

If the user mentions that he wants to take a particular test, I transfer it to the view function corresponding to that test. In that view function, I generate the list of questions using the model for that particular test,and pass it in the Httpresponse function to an html file.

What I want to do is generate a variable no of checkboxes , n*4 where n = no of questions in the test. For each checkbox, the name attribute has to be set. For example, i could set them as t1, t2 .. tz. When the user clicks submit, it goes to another page where i check the answers.

The template language in Django, is similar to python, but doesnt allow for assignment of variables. How would I assign names to checkboxes then, as I dont know the no of checkboxes beforehand?

Comment: Can you draw a mockup to show what you are trying to do?  I sometime find the django form to have some limitation when it comes to a dynamic number of widgets or AJAX heavy actions.  In that case, I'll just go back to the basics with manual form building.  It's crude and against DRY but it gets the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a for loop to display your questions you can use the `forloop.counter` template filter to get access to a counter variable that will allow you to enumerate the checkboxes.  For example,

```
{% for question in questions_list %}
    {{ question }}
    <input type="checkbox" name="t{{ forloop.counter }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah, just a small modification to your code, adding the double quotes at the end of forloop.counter}}, and it worked! Thanks a lot!